Почему созданная функция в postgresql возвращает большой некорректное значение?
Есть запрос Создать и выполнить функцию, в которой по номеру рейса вывести количество свободных мест.
ДИАГРАММА БД:

КОД ФУНКЦИИ:
create function get_free_seat_of_flighs(flight_number character) returns int as
$$
declare TOTAL_SEAT int;
declare TOTAL_FREE_SEAT int;
begin
    select count(*) into TOTAL_SEAT
    from seats s
    inner join flights f ON s.aircraft_code = f.aircraft_code
    where f.flight_no = flight_number;
    
    select count(*) into TOTAL_FREE_SEAT
    from boarding_passes bd
    inner join flights f ON bd.flight_id = f.flight_id 
    where f.flight_no = flight_number;
    
    return TOTAL_SEAT - TOTAL_FREE_SEAT;
end
$$
language 'plpgsql'

Функция принимает номеру рейса, в моем случае PG0134
SELECT  get_free_seat_of_flighs('PG0134')
Но почему функция возвращает 5354 разве не слишком много места для одного рейса ?
Или может я не понимаю как работает аэропорт ?
РЕЙСЫ ЗАПИСАННЫЕ В Таблицу flights:


добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! как задавать хорошие вопросы про sql?

Ну если вы не управляющий в аэропорту, то детально врят ли понимаете работу аэропорта(я тоже не знаю), однако, тут у вас не аэропорт, а таблицы. Вы смотрели по отдельности, что в таблицах лежит, какие там данные, какие каунты считаются в каждом из селектов?

И на сколько я помню, номер рейса, почти как номер автобуса. Т.е. номер рейса это некое ИД борта_самолета + маршрут и оно выполняется регулярно. Ваш рейс PG0134 - это полет из города А в город Б. Из города Б в город А этот борт полетит под другим номером, но из А в Б опять с номером PG0134. Где то должны быть еще к рейсам расписание приложено и у стататуса полета не должно быть "завершен". Ну как следствие по номеру рейса искать ближайший или какой там вам нужен вылет и по нему отбирать места.

по номеру рейса вывести количество свободных мест Без указания точной даты задача ну просто идиотская. Сейчас функция тащит вообще количество свободных мест суммарно на указанном рейсе за все даты, за которые этот рейс уже введён. 50 на завтра, 40 на послезавтра, 45 через месяц... а всего расписано рейсов на три месяца вперёд, и суммарно на них сейчас пять тыщ не забронированных ещё билетов...

TOTAL_FREE_SEAT по вычислению скорее назвать TOTAL_occupied_SEAT. Можете уменьшить количество свободных мест, проверив статус рейса. Если уже улетел - не считайте. Или возьмите  только ближайший (последний) рейс - будет еще меньше. Уточните структуру таблицы Flights. Какие рейсы там записаны? Если actual_departure не пустое - шарик улетел.

@ValNik Добавил картинку заполненной таблицы flights

Похоже, вам надо вычислять места по flight_no, flight_id. Если результатов будет несколько - выдать по каждому рейсу, либо по рейсу, у которого статус = sheduled. Пытайте того кто вам дал задание)
